# how to hide all rows in Ag-grid while loading data

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I'm using `"ag-grid-angular": "^25.3.0"` and `"ag-grid-community": "^25.3.0"`

while loading the data from the server, a second before rendering the grid, there is one empty row shown.

in some examples that I found, I saw they added a loader gif in the empty row, but in my case, I have a cellRendererFramework that will show default data when it gets no data. so this can't work with adding any loader.

I don't want that row to be shown at all.

is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Initialize the rowData variable with empty array. That should work

Comment: @DrashtiDobariya it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ag-grid provides an inbuilt overlay to show when the data is being loaded.

Methods:

```
// show 'loading' overlay
this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();

// show 'no rows' overlay
this.gridApi.showNoRowsOverlay();

// clear all overlays
this.gridApi.hideOverlay();
```

In normal scenarios, we do not call these methods as grid itself manages it for us.
However, in some cases such as yours, we can utilize this methods for our advantage.

Call `this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay()` method before you call the server for data.
After getting response from server, call `this.gridApi.hideOverlay();`

```
private getData(): void {
    this.gridApi.showLoadingOverlay();
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
        // do something with data
        this.gridApi.hideOverlay();
    })

}
```

You can also create custom overlays if you want. (Refer link mentioned below)

Drawback:
Here, although the grid body is tinted but the previous rows are still shown. However, since after getting the response, we add new rows, it should be fine.

For more details, read this [link](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/overlays/)

Comment: I use the overlay, the overlay has opacity: 0.5 that's why I can see the empty row